# React Native Navigation Back button crashes android

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-navigation

*EDIT: this only happens when going back to the first screen in the stack...*

i have an app that works when ran in Expo Go but when i build the project in dev-client or an internal build it will crash every time i hit the back button. It includes 5 stack screens inside of a tab navigator.

im using
`navigation.goBack()`

ive also tried `navigation.navigate("<page>")` which shockingly doesn't work if im trying to return to a previous page, but works if i'm moving forward to a new page.

i have tried changing the button into a Pressable component, a TouchableOpacity component, using the stock navigation header component. Absolutely nothing works. However, it works flawlessly on iOS.

I do not receive ANY error messages from the log, and i am using a physical device. I think its very strange that it works fine on Expo-Go but not when built.

Repo: https://github.com/keaton569/OceanDriveApp/tree/main

Comment: Please share the code so that we can help :)

Comment: added repo to description